# Maven Project after deploy won't establish a connection to the Database file

Tags: java, database, sqlite, maven, javafx

It works well when I start it from the IDE (as a Java Application), but when I deploy it (maven native command) and start it via .exe file, it's not able to find even the directory.

**The problem solves if I write 'jdbc:sqlite:SeeYourUse.db', but I thought I'm supposed to keep all of my resources under 'src/main/resources'.**

By the way, all the images load properly.

Can somebody explain where could the problem hide?

Here is a part of my project's POM. Basically, it contains a dependency to SQLite (that is downloaded and works properly) and JavaFX plugin (that works properly as well)

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>8.2.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>com.SeeYourUse.Main</mainClass>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.twdata.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mojo-executor</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1.0</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.SeeYourUse.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>


</build>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.2</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>


<url>https://github.com/CrazzyBeer/SeeYourUse</url>
```

Here is the method that connects to the Database.

```
private void connect() {

        try {

            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:src/main/resources/DB/SeeYourUse.db");


        } catch (Exception e) {
            //System.err.println("Couldn't connect to the DB");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

        // System.out.println("DB Opened successfully");
    }
```

Here is the error stack trace I get

```
java.sql.SQLException: path to 'src/main/resources/DB/SeeYourUse.db': 'E:\Programming\Java\Work\SeeYourUse\target\jfx\native\SeeYourUse-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\app\src' does not exist
    at org.sqlite.Conn.open(Conn.java:103)
    at org.sqlite.Conn.<init>(Conn.java:57)
    at org.sqlite.JDBC.createConnection(JDBC.java:77)
    at org.sqlite.JDBC.connect(JDBC.java:64)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
    at com.SeeYourUse.SQLiteDB.connect(SQLiteDB.java:30)
    at com.SeeYourUse.SQLiteDB.createMessages(SQLiteDB.java:111)
    at com.SeeYourUse.SQLiteDB.init(SQLiteDB.java:96)
    at com.SeeYourUse.Main.start(Main.java:21)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Can you log the exception and [edit] your question to include its stack trace? It might also be useful to check the contents of the bundled jar file and make sure it includes everything you need (including the sqlite library).

Comment: Sure, i'll do that in a moment

Comment: The bundled jar file includes SQLiteDB.class, if that's what is needed

Comment: For the stack trace, I meant the exception that presumably is caught in the catch block in the `connect` method: can you log that and post it?

Comment: Here we go, now it looks cleaner

Comment: As a additional question, can I somehow launch the application as if it was deployed without actually deploying it? It takes a load of time to build it everytime I make a change.

Comment: Mkay, the problem must be in the path. But all the images load properly, even though they are in the src/main/resources/images, when as the DB is in the src/main/resources/DB.

Comment: Well, you're kind of unlikely to have a `src` directory included in a deployed application...

Comment: How to include it? It says that this folder is included in the Build Path

Comment: Okay, this starts to be strange.

Comment: I can see images from resources, but I can't access the DB and I can't acess a HTML file to put it inside a webview

Comment: `src` is the *source* directory. You don't want it to be there at runtime. These resources are copied to the build directory (i.e. the location to which the class files, generated by compiling the java files, are deployed) and then bundled into the jar file. You may need to configure your IDE to properly deploy all your resources. You should access these resources via their [resource name](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/resources.html)

Comment: What do I do if I have a HTML file inside my resources and I want to load it into a webview? I can't use InputStream for that.
And I still can't understand how to properly add my database...

Comment: For the HTML file, just get the URL of the resource. You don't need the input stream at all. The database is more complex and exactly how you handle it depends on what you are doing. Obviously if you need to write to it, which you almost certainly do, you need it to be on the user's machine, not bundled with the app. How you do that depends on your requirements.